# NodeJS: How to fix different node module version?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to start a nodeJS application, but I do get the error

```
Error: The module '/Users/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I already run `npm install` and `npm rebuild`. But still the same error...

Comment: check a list of npm commands. Try npm update modulename

Comment: Please note that the answer here by robertklep is a much better answer than the one on the duplicate redirection page which suggests that you delete the entire node_module folder.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `bcrypt` package needs to be rebuild, because it was initially installed with another version of Node.js.

Try this:

```
npm rebuild bcrypt --update-binary
```

for yarn users:

```
yarn add bcrypt --force
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Still having warn `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57`

Comment: @spaceman try reinstalling `bcrypt` in that case (or first uninstall, then install again).

Comment: @robertklep How to reinstall `bcrypt`? Doing `npm install bcrypt --save` does not help.

Comment: @SuhailGupta you have to be more specific, or perhaps even create a new question about the specific problem you're having.

Comment: If you use node nightly, it's not enough to copy the `node` binary to `/usr/local/bin/node`, but you need also to copy `lib/node_modules` and `include/node` to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and `/usr/local/include/node` respectively, where later is most important as its sets the new NODE_MODULE_VERSION when you build packages locally. After copying the files, make sure to wipe your node_modules from your project and reinstall _everything_.

Comment: Great working for me this solution.

Comment: If this fails, you can always do (the classic) `rm -f /node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm i`. Bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but it works.

Comment: I tried everything for this problem, completely wiping my node_modules and reinstalling, running `npm rebuild` multiple times, changing Node versions. Nothing worked, until I ran `npm rebuild my_module_name --update-binary`. So glad I found this answer!