# Oracledb.node was compiled against a different node.js version using

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm facing an issue that can't connect to oracle DB.
[image]
If I use an example from [oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) that works fine.
As message error said, I tried `npm rebuild` or `npm install`

I read and did this already [nodejs error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

However, there are still errors.

This is my project dir:

[image]

I'm using oracledb: version": "2.3.0"

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you're in `C:\Users\xuanh\Downloads\vhrm`, I'm guessing you downloaded a zip file, extracted the contents, and then tried to run the app. The person that zipped the files was likely using a different platform (Mac, Linux, etc.) or a different version of Node.js than you are. Try deleting `C:\Users\xuanh\Downloads\vhrm\node_modules\oracledb` and then rerun `npm install`.

Comment: You're right. My co-worker sent it to me as zip file. I already deleted then run `npm install`. However, there are still error.

Comment: Did you install the instant client libraries that the driver depends on? I think this is the install doc you need: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin

Comment: I installed it. Note: I can run the example that I got from oracle github

Comment: If you can run the example, then you should be good to go. Something must be different from when you run the example and when you run your code. What directory are you in when you run the example?