# Upgrading from node 8 to node 10: error regarding "module compiled against a different Node.js version"

Tags: node.js

I am now getting the following error when I run my node app.  It has only occurred after I upgraded from `node 8.12.0` to `node 10.13.0` (which is now "[recommended for most users](https://nodejs.org/en/)").  The problem seems to relate to [node-expat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat), which I don't use directly but which is a dependency of [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) (which I *do* use directly).

```
/root/workspace/myapp/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88
        throw e
        ^

Error: The module '/root/workspace/myapp/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:682:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at bindings (/root/workspace/myapp/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/workspace/myapp/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
```

What do I need to do to fix this?  Yes, I have completely removed `node_modules` and done `npm install` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)... doesn't help.

Comment: Try to also delete `package-lock.json`

Comment: @GabrielBleu there is no `package-lock.json`

Comment: Did you try `npm cache clean -f` (and reinstall everything)? There were multiple issues with npm registry in recent weeks. See the [incident](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/) reports.

Comment: I wonder whether it has something to do with this commit made 3 months ago to `node-expat`: https://github.com/astro/node-expat/commit/822197d0a0f1b69e4a2cd0f4010d54b9c66d0ec3.  The `xml2json` package is still referencing version `2.3.16` of `node-expat` in its `package-lock.json` (see https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json/blob/master/package-lock.json).

Comment: @lependu that doesn't help either.  Re my comment just above... could it be that?  How do I force a different version of `node-expat` on `xml2json` when `xml2json` isn't my own module... I'm just `require`ing that as a dependency in my node app (and `package.json`)?

Comment: @drmrbrewer double check, node 8.12.0 ships with npm 6.4.1 which creates a package-lock.json every time you install.

Comment: @GabrielBleu definitely no `package-lock.json` :-) ... I've disabled it with `npm config set package-lock false`

Comment: I am afraid you can't tweak 3rd party module dependency. Maybe `node-gyp rebuild` can help.

Comment: I have no idea why it is working now, but it is :-/  Seems that several iterations of doing `nvm uninstall 10.13.0` / `nvm install 10.13.0` / `rm -fr node_modules` / `npm cache clean -f` / `npm install` has resulting in a working installation.  No idea why it wasn't working straight away.