# Problem running AWS Lambda function with Sharp library

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, sharp

I created a lambda function through the aws-amplify CLI by following an AWS workshop (https://amplify-workshop.go-aws.com/70_generating_thumbnails/10_creating_a_photo_processor_lambda.html).  Seems that there is a problem with conflicting versions of Node.js somewhere.

I believe that the sharp library is the problem, so I have tried to change the version to the latest to see if that would do anything, but it did not fix the issue.

CloudWatch error log:

```
module initialization error: Error
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:10:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

I believe there is a simple fix, but I am unsure where the source of the problem lies.  Thank you.

Comment: what node version are you using? lambda only supports `Node.js` `6.10` and `8.10`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html

Comment: My Lambda function is using v8.10, sorry that I forgot to mention that.  As NODE_MODULE_VERSION_67 relates to Node.js version 11, I am wondering where that is coming from?  The sharp library?

Comment: You might be bundling from local system, which probably has `node` 11 installed.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio

Comment: Change your local node version to `8.10`, remove `node_modules`, `npm install`, bundle folder including `node_modules` and upload to lambda. it should work.

Comment: Alright, I will change my local node version to 8.10.  Should work.

Comment: Leaving it as answer just for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have built your `node_modules` using lambda incompatible version of `Node.js`. Lambda only [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html) Node.js 6.10 and 8.10.

Try changing your local node version to `8.10`, remove `node_modules`, `npm install`, bundle folder including `node_modules` and upload to lambda. This should work.

Answer (score 5):

Use your aws lambda node version when installing sharp.

```
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=10.4.1 sharp
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old. I had the same trouble and discovered the issue is when we build the project (layer) in windows machine and try to run it in lambda. The dependencies built in Linux and Windows environments are different.

Try building & creating the zip file in a linux environment. That should fix your issue.

[image: Windows & Linux node_modules for Sharp]

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
npm_config_arch=x64 npm_config_platform=linux npm install sharp
```

For some reason, arguments did not work.