# Error: Cannot find module 'ffi' compiling ElectronJS project

Tags: node.js, electron, ffi

I'm new on NodeJS/ElectronJS.
I need to use User.dll functions.
My actual situation is:

Windows 10 on Parallels
Node -v = 10.15.3 (LTS)
NPM -v = 6.9.0

I installed:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

npm install win32-api

npm install ffi (gives me several "\ffi.cc(***): warning C4996: 'v8::Value::To Object': .... deprecated)
```

I added var FFI = require('node-ffi'); in my "main.js" and when I try to compile with npm start

I obtain this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-ffi' at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584:15)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps fixed my issue (major pain in the ***)

Make sure the node gyp compiler is installed

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Install the FFI package into the local project

```
npm install --save ffi
```

I also needed to install ref-array (part of example code)

```
npm install ref-array --save
```

Go into the node_modules/ffi directory and do an NPM install to make sure it's got all it's dependencies

```
cd node_modules/ffi
npm install
```

Get back out of the node_modules/ffi folder

```
cd ../../
```

Install the electron rebuild tools

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Run the electron rebuild script (I'm running on Windows, hence .cmd)

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

So simple (NOT) :D

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

[How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

using `npm install`

and then

[Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

using

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`