# Node module was compiled against diffferent node module 67

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have a node project that was compiled under node module version 67, but now i am getting an error that it requires node module version 69.

```
usb_bindings.node was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen]
```

Does anyone know how i could resolve this issue?

Comment: please post the exact question not just the error message alone.

Comment: Did you try npm rebuild as it says in the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE\_MODULE\_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to compiling the node-usb module,
This article shows how to re-compiling correcly
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

```
cd /path-to-module/
npm install -g node-gyp
node-gyp rebuild --target=1.2.3 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers
//replace target version with your version of electron
```