# The edge module has not been pre compiled for node js version V12.13.0

Tags: npm, build, electron, electron-packager, packager

I have try to packaging the electron app in local.

**I have tried the following steps:**

```
npm install electron-packager

npm install -g electron-packager

npm install -g electron

npm start
```

I have got the following exception

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249103/node-module-was-compiled-against-diffferent-node-module-67/56249648#56249648 Please refer to my answer in the above link