# Node version different when using NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I tried to find a duplicate question, there are similar ones but I still don't understand what's going on..

I just installed node and npm on Ubuntu 20.04 with

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

And followed the Electron quick start [tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start), and added this line to the beginning of my main.js:

```
console.log("node version: " + process.versions["node"]);
```

When I run my app with `npm start`, I see (both on the console and on the app) node version 16.13.0, but when I run the app with `node main`, I see the version as 10.19.0, which is also what `node -v`  shows.

I can probably "fix" this issue by updating node, but I would like to understand what is going on here.. Is NPM using a different node version or something?

Thanks

**Edit**
I tried this with an empty node app, just made `npm init` and set `start: "node index.js"` in `package.json`, this time both `node index.js` and `npm start` show the same version (10.19.0) so I'm guessing Electron is somehow reading a wrong node version?

Comment: I think electron is showing the version of the node embedded into it. It's not the version which is in your system.

Comment: Yes, I just found this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/232#issuecomment-433864297). But now I'm more confused.. I thought electron was a module of node.. But node is also a module of electron?

Comment: Electron uses node as a shared library. Check this out to get more details on it, https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-internals-using-node-as-a-library

Comment: Thank you! You can post this as an answer I guess :)

Comment: Nope as per SO, just references to links can't be an actual answer. :-)

Comment: You need to specify the version check out this click [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64719704/electron-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DJHemath is spot on. Electron has Node and Chromium as internal libraries. IE: Node is a module of Electron.

Therefore, the version you are seeing within your Electron application is the Node version that is bundled with Electron.

When Electron is updated, the versions of Node and Chromium are often updated as well. An overview of this can be seen on the Electron homepage "Releases" cards (latest, beta, alpha and nightly).

Additionally, for historical purposes, version updates of these two dependencies can be seen on the [Stable Releases](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable) page.

Thus, in summary, changing your system's installed Node version **will not** affect the version of Node used within your Electron application(s).