# compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, node-sass, sass-loader

Npm install is successful. npm start throws below error.

no dependency on bcrpt and node-pre-gyp
Followed most of the comments from similar questions like clean cache, rebuild, delete node-modules and install again but none worked for me. Is there a problem with Node version??
Node: 11.15.0
npm: 6.7.0

** Error message on npm start **

````
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: The module '\\?\D:\_Install\win32-x64-64_binding.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:857:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\syedabu.c\Downloads\ReactJSBlueprint\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\syedabu.c\Downloads\ReactJSBlueprint\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
 @ ./styles/main.scss 2:14-145 21:1-42:3 22:19-150
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi @babel/polyfill react-hot-loader/patch react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient react-error-overlay ./src/index.jsx```

Expected to start without error. Please help me to resolve.
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE\_MODULE\_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

Answer (score 6):

i am facing the same issue.
but this method worked for me.
you have to install the required nodejs version .
in your case , you have to install NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67 which mean you have to install node version 11.0.0 to 11.15.0 .(you can know the version from this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ )
once it is installed.
you just type this command in the terminal.
**npm rebuild**