# How to change my node version on my computer

Tags: npm, bcrypt

I updated my node version from 10.16.3 to 12.14.0.
3 months ago, I made api by using node js. At that time, it worked well.
But now it throws errors.

These are what I did and errors.

```
D:\Projects\Project\Mean & Mern\Angular\data\API>node server
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The module '\\?\D:\Projects\Project\Mean & Mern\Angular\data\API\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Project\Mean & Mern\Angular\data\API\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
```

I refer to this url: [Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

But nothing helps me.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **nvm** to select your preferred node version with ease.
Check this repo for details: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 5):

I have found is to just use the **nodejs.org** site

```
1. go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

2. find version you want and click download

3. click the .pkg executable and follow the installation instructions
```

One way is to use NVM, the Node Version Manager.

You can find it at https://github.com/creationix/nvm

It allows you to easily install and manage multiple versions of node. Here's a snippet from the help:

```
Usage:
nvm install <version>       Download and install a <version>
nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>
nvm ls                      List versions (installed versions are blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

Before I did do like this.

```
npm install
node server
```

But I couldn't run it.
I try many times to fix, and finally I found this!

```
npm install canvas or yarn add canvas
```

And now it works!
:D