# getting error in node js - NODE_MODULE_VERSION

Tags: node.js, node-modules

when i run command `npm start`,  i am getting this error

```
Error: The module '/var/www/oxygen/mirari-api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? i am using node version `10.13.0`, i tried a lot googling but it didn't help me yet, if anyone have face that issue then please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you install your npm modules with different version and then try to run you code it with another version. Try deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried re-installing it?
There is a simillar question here:

[Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

Resuming, you could try:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/bcrypt
$ npm install
// or
$ yarn
```

Or:

1- Require all dependencies you need in the main.js file that is run by electron. (this seemed to be the first important part for me)

2- Run npm i -D electron-rebuild to add the electron-rebuild package

3- Remove the node-modules folder, as well as the packages-lock.json file.

4- Run npm i to install all modules.

5- Run ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild (.\node_modules.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd for Windows) to rebuild everything