# Why do I get this error when @pdftron/pdfnet-node package is used and how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, pdf, electron, pdftron

When I use a function that uses pdfnet-node package I get this error message (it's an electron app if it is a necessary info):

```
Error: The module '\\?\G:\project_folder\node_modules\@pdftron\pdfnet-node\lib\addon.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using 
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 87. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall using `npm install`

Comment: Yea, I did this several times and it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio

Comment: Did you read this?
**To install for Electron, runtime and target options are needed. For example, For Electron 6, we need to run npm i @pdftron/pdfnet-node --runtime=electron --target=6.0.0. Note that we need to use 6.0.0 for all Electron 6 versions.**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pdftron/pdfnet-node

Comment: Thanks, I just did it and that error is gone, now I have an exception that says it's unable to find a printer

Comment: So the original issue is resolved for you? As for the "unable to find a printer" did you ask this somewhere else? If not, then you should start a new question so you can get further assistance.