# Can't use library on NW.js - was compiled against a different Node.js version using

Tags: node.js, electron, pcap, nwjs

My problem is that I want to import [this](https://github.com/roman-balzer/cap) library on a desktop app based on NW.js (the template is [here](https://github.com/elegantweb/nwjs-vue)).

```
import Cap from 'cap-rbfork' //set on a vue.js view
```

When I start the app, it doesn't load the page and I get this error on the window console:

```
  VM245:11 Uncaught Error: The module '/home/user/app/node_modules/cap-rbfork/build/Release/cap.node'
    was compiled against a different Node.js version using
    NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
    NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
    the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`). Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955)
    at Module.load (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:756)
    at Function.Module._load (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:669)
    at Module.require (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796)
    at require (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (:9080/home/user/app/node_modules/cap-rbfork/lib/Cap.js:3)
    at Module._compile (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:910)
    at Module.load (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:756)
    at Function.Module._load (:9080/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:669)
```

**@Jaredcheeda**

I followed your instructions, and I created a new NWjs app with the template you suggested.

```
  mounted(){
    var Cap = this.nw.require('cap-rbfork')
    console.log(Cap) //it lists properties
    console.log(Cap.Cap.deviceList()) //or Cap.deviceList(), but the app crashes anyway, without reporting the reason, except SIGSEGV
  }
```

If I visit the page from the browser, I get this error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897 Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
    at eval (cap.node:1)
    at Object../node_modules/cap-rbfork/build/Release/cap.node (chunk-vendors.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Cap.js?c745:3)
    at Object../node_modules/cap-rbfork/lib/Cap.js (chunk-vendors.js:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at VueComponent.mounted (App.vue?234e:37)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863)
```

I don't know this means that NW needs to be downgraded, so it can match the correct node-gyp version. I created an Electron project, and following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796884/13072160) to a similar problem, it worked. Is there a NW equivalent to electron-rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Completely uninstall your globally installed version of Node
2. Install a Node Version Manager:

   - Linux/OSX - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
   - Windows 8+ - https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows
   - Windows 7 - https://github.com/nullivex/nodist
3. Check the version of Node that is built in to NW.js

   - https://nwjs.io/versions.json
   - or `console.log(process.versions);` in NW.js
4. Use your `nvm` tool of choice to install and switch to the matching Node version
5. Delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder
6. Do `npm install` this will download/build files specific to your global Node versions, which should match the version built in to NW.js

With all that said, Vue-CLI's Webpack/Babel set up is designed to import/bundle/tree-shake BROWSER code, not NODE code. So doing `import x from 'y'` won't work if it involves native code, node-bindings, executables, or Node specific code.

NW.js uses `require` instead of `import` to handle importing Node modules.

- **See:** [NW-Vue-CLI-Example](https://github.com/nwutils/nw-vue-cli-example)

You may also need to change your NW.js version if you are having issues with Node-GYP/NW-GYP:

- **See:** https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/guide-to-nw-js-versions-5d38#0392-20190627

Comment: The template linked to is just a general Vue/NW.js template. It will not solve your problem. You need to read the rest of my post and try those things in your project, or in that boilerplate.