# Docker run fails "return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));"

Tags: node.js, docker, express, bcrypt

im trying to make a dockerfile and run my code into this container. im getting following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1187
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1187:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

My application works fine without docker.
i also tryed to remove bcrypt like in this question: [Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR ./
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

.dockerignore:

```
node_modules
upload
export
converage
.git
.tmp
.vscode
.github
.env
```

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?

Comment: ` docker run containername`

Comment: And, do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the host's `node_modules` directory?

Comment: my .dockerignore looks like: node_modules
upload
export
converage
.git
.tmp
.vscode
.github
.env

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is this resolved for you?

Comment: i faced the similar issue, adding node_modules to the .dockerignore solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `.dockerignore`

The basic `.dockerignore` look like

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Comment: Add it where? In the same folder on the host as the Dockerfile? Or inside the docker image? Or what?

Comment: Yeah, in the same folder on the host as the dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You should try to delete node_modules. This helped me.

```
$rm -rf node_modules/
$npm update
```